# How to restore table from dump to database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I create a table dump using pg_dump:

```
pg_dump -h server1 -U postgres -t np_points gisurfo > D:\np_point.sql
```

After I go in psql and says:

```
-f D:\np_point.sql
```

But get list of standart PostgreSQL tables.

Next I try to exequte np_point.sql in pgAdmin and get error:

```
ERROR:  Syntax error (near: "1")
LINE 78: 1 Сухово 75244822005 75644000 Челябинская обл. Нязепетровски...
```

Its snippet of this sql where I get error:

```
COPY np_point (gid, full_name, okato, oktmo, obl_name, region_nam, the_geom) FROM stdin;
1   Сухово  75244822005 75644000    Челябинская обл.    Нязепетровский район    0101000020E6100000312A7936BD9F4D402A3C580DE9FF4B40
```

How can I restore table from sql file?

**UPDATE**

PostgreSQL 8.4

And first part of sql file.

```
PostgreSQL database dump

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = off;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET escape_string_warning = off;

SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

--
-- Name: np_point; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres; Tablespace: 
 --

CREATE TABLE np_point (
gid integer NOT NULL,
full_name character varying(254),
okato character varying(254),
oktmo character varying(254),
obl_name character varying(254),
region_nam character varying(254),
the_geom geometry,
CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_the_geom CHECK ((st_ndims(the_geom) = 2)),
CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_the_geom CHECK (((geometrytype(the_geom) = 'POINT'::text) OR (the_geom IS NULL))),
CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_the_geom CHECK ((st_srid(the_geom) = 4326))
);
```

Comment: Which versions of postgres? What are the attributes of the databases you're dumping from and importing into? What do the schemas look like of the databases you're dumping from and importing into?

Comment: @wich: i update question. Please look at it. Its what you want to see?

Comment: did you install posgis in destinations db?

Comment: @francs: Yeah, of couse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install posgis in destinations db? If not , install postgis first。

If you install postgis and still have the problem, try to dump a table without geometry filed
and restore it in another db ,and see if the problem still appears.

Comment: pg_dump -h server1 -E UTF8 -U postgres -t "schemaname.np_points" gisurfo > D:\np_point.sql